# SetTimeout not working inside async eventListener

Tags: javascript

In the following function I am adding an eventlistener to every li, up until the setTimeout everything work as expected.
  Neither the console.log nor the populateForm() execute. I have tried a bunch of different methods but nothing seams to work.

```
async function addClickListener() {
  const items = document.querySelectorAll(".li");
  items.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", async (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      sessionStorage.clear();
      const movieData = await createMovieObject(evt.currentTarget);
      sessionStorage.setItem("movieData", JSON.stringify(movieData));
      clearMovieList();
      removeHidden();
      switchToSearch();
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("hello");
        populateForm();
      }, 5000);
    });
  });
}
```

I tried calling `await delay(5000);` instead of the setTimeout like above but this doesn't work either

```
 const delay = (ms) =>
  new Promise(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("hello");
      populateForm();
    }, ms);
  });
```

Here is the populateForm() function

```
function populateForm() {
  const check = document.querySelector("#added_movies");
  console.log(sessionStorage);
  console.log(check);
}
```

Here is the switchToSearch() function, it seams that this is causing the issue as I am changing links and the console is maybe reset (just an assumption)?!

```
function switchToSearch() {
  window.location.href = "./movies";
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use async and await ?

Comment: Do you just want to make shure that switchToSearch is finished?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the setTimeout, but as sidenote I would suggest adding an event listener on the parent container instead every individual li  element.

Comment: @DankDizaster, yes it needs to be since createMovieObject(evt.currentTarget) is making an API call.

Comment: @JipHelsen, yes correct, the problem I am facing is that populateForm() (which has a querrySelector) returns as null

Comment: Think of this if your code has 50 li items and as of your function it will wait for 50*5000 milliseconds which is approximately equal to 4.16 minutes.setTimeout will make your code much much slower since each call will happen after an interval of 5 seconds.

Comment: @html_programmer, that is how I started, however, since I need the event data from the specific child that didn't work

Comment: Can't you just make populateForm() an async function and await him in a variable?

Comment: @NaveenkumarM, I don't follow, right now all I am doing is adding an on click event on 10 items, when I click the item then the functions in the eventListener are executed... Am I misunderstanding eventListener completely?

Comment: @JipHelsen, I have just added the populateFrom function in my question. I don't think making it async will solve anything as the issue is that it is executing before the page is fully loaded and therefore returning null.

Comment: Can you make sure that `const items = document.querySelectorAll(".li");` line correct?

Comment: @Sparrow, that line is working correctly. Otherwise no code in the eventListener block would be working as intended

Comment: I found there is nothing wrong with `setTimeout` and that should work in async too.

Comment: Can you check if there any error logged on the console?

Comment: @Sparrow, there are no errors, however I just saw that when I remove the switchToSearch() function the setTimeout is working. I will add the code to the question

Comment: If the `console.log` of the `setTimeout` does not show, then the reason for that is likely the contents of `switchToSearch`.

Comment: @t.niese, you are right, that is causing the issue, I have added my code above

Comment: @NaveenkumarM no, that explanation does not make any sense. The `setTimeout` is within the event listener and there is not reason why they should accumulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `window.location.href = "./movies";`  a new document is loaded and all Timeouts, EventListeners, … are released. So your registered timeout won’t be executed.

Comment: I see, I started assuming something like that. Is there a way to change page and still execute the functions. 
The idea is the following :
click on the item -> store data of item in session -> change page -> query select a tag on the new page -> insert session data into tag

Answer (score 0):

I have marked @t.niese ansewer as accepted since this is the underlying problem I am facing. 
One thing that I would like to note though is that although code in the setTimeout() did not work, code that followed, for example an console.log('I am on the new page') would work right after the switchToSearch();.

Anyway, I have continued now and made it work via an onload:

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/movies") {
  window.onload = populateForm;
  console.log(sessionStorage);
}
```